# Iframe integration issue

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to make the iframe not take over the main focus of the scrolling withing the page. I need to be able to scroll the page entirely to the bottom even though the cursor hovers over the i frame.

http://gyazo.com/e11d47e10b2d5a8b9769ae64609721e5

I need to make it so that the parent page gets to bottom before the iframe starts scrolling so it won't show only half of the iframe.

I have access to the iframe contents aswell.

http://jsbin.com/rifipezeyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: html page integrated via a basic iframe with a javascript to control the height

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rifipezeyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output